# Ext JS: How to write custom styles CSS/SCSS for Grid column header?

Tags: html, css, extjs, sass

I want to override an existing style for Grid column header.

```
 {
  text: '<table style="padding:"0px""><tr 
           bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><th>abc</th></tr><tr><td style="border-top: 1px 
            solid black; padding-top: 10px;" align="center">Test</td></tr> 
              </table>',
  renderer: me.checkboxRenderer,
  align: 'center',
  flex: 1,
  padding: 0
}
```

Issue: Whenever I try to add padding style to this column, it is applying the padding for the higher-level Div with class `x-column-header x-column-header-default`. The table padding (column header text) is set to zero. When everything is set to zero, after this grid was rendered there was another div with class `x-column-header-inner` in between higher level div and the table, this div is adding some dynamic padding which I was unable to make it to zero.

Idea: I want to add padding zero by overwriting the style with Div id `gridcolumn-2573-titleEl` or class `x-column-header-inner` in a CSS/SCSS file.

How do we create a new CSS/SCSS file and link/import it to Ext JS file so that I can overwrite the middle Div style padding to zero.

Comment: It would be best to do all the styling in a separate CSS file, not inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Sencha Cmd (you should), the folder structure is usually as follows:

- app <- js files
- sass

  - src <- scss files

For a JS file named `Application.js` in the app directory, put an SCSS file named `Application.scss` into the `sass/src` directory. For a JS file named `Main.js` in the `app/view` directory, put an SCSS file named `Main.scss` into the `sass/src/view` directory. The content of that file will be added to the CSS **on the next build** (but only if the js file itself is also added to the build).

Do **not** use autogenerated ids like "gridcolumn-2573-titleEl" in your CSS. The "2573" is an auto-incrementing number and your CSS will inevitably break, maybe already on the next reload. The recommended approach is to add on your column a unique `userCls`:

```
  renderer: me.checkboxRenderer,
  userCls: 'checkboxRendererCls'
```

and then add a specially crafted CSS rule into the SCSS file that matches the JS file where you added the `userCls`:

```
.checkboxRendererCls .x-column-header-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. I have tried this but didnt see the SCSS styles applied to component (Grid.Panel). My project doesn't have a folder "sass", I created with the similar layer of where my JS file lives - sass->src->level1->level2->view->abc.scss and added styles. As this is new folder, my build.xml is not picking these new files and again i have added code to copy these scss files to build dir, even then it builds but styles are not showing up. I have tried checking with style name by view page source but didn't find this style.

Comment: @IAmRkrishnaV21 These values are default values for new projects, maybe they vary between Cmd versions or someone changed the defaults in your project. You can check app.json for specifics.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, you are correct. The file app.json was defaulted to one particular folder to use sass files. I have changed that now. Thanks so much for providing the solution.